# React HOC to use Context API in Lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a **React HOC** to access the context in a lifecycle method.

I am getting the following error...

`(0, _withContext.withContext)` is not a function. `(In '(0, _withContext.withContext)(TestScreen)','(0, _withContext.withContext)' is undefined)`

The error most likely lies in the way I wrote withContext HOC. I am new to writing HOC codes. Can help point out where my error lies for my HOC? Thanks

**In withContext HOC**

```
import { MyContext } from "../context/MyProvider";

const withContext = Component => {
  return props => {
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {context => {
        return <Component {...props} context={context} />;
      }}
    </MyContext.Consumer>;
  };
};
```

**In TestScreen.js**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.context);
  }

export default withContext(TestScreen);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't exported the `withContext` function and hence its an error in using it

```
export const withContext = Component => {
  return props => {
    <MyContext.Consumer>
      {context => {
        return <Component {...props} context={context} />;
      }}
    </MyContext.Consumer>;
  };
};
```

and then import like

```
import { withContext } from 'path/to/withContext'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not explicitly returning your component, try this:

```
const withContext = Component => {
  return props => {
   return (
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => {
          return <Component {...props} context={context} />;
        }}
      </MyContext.Consumer>;
    );
  };
};
```